# Jquery Read 10 rows from table, wait 10 seconds, read 10 more rows

Tags: jquery

I need to read the data from a table starting with the first 10 rows, then wait 10 seconds and then the next 10 rows.
Rad, pause, read pause read until end of table.

I am trying with this code but it read the first 10 rows, wait and the reads all the rest.

```
$('.sendmultimail').on('click', function(){
        var count = 0;
        $(".tablerow").each(function() {
            // this should loop through all the selected elements
            if(count < 10){
                $(this).addClass("bg-success");
                count++;
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => { 
                    $(this).addClass("bg-success");
                    console.log('Howdy!'); 
                    count = 0;  
                }, 10000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there another way to use timeout?